# How to load json file before runapp in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to load json content before runApp in main of my flutter app.
I have a Future function (**LoadLanguage**) which load json file in a variable(**LanguageData**) , so I can use value of mentioned variable in my app:

```
Future<void> LoadLanguage(BuildContext context,String lng)
async {
  String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/translations/"+lng+".json");
  LanguageData = jsonDecode(data);
}
```

problem is my app must wait until **LanguageData** be loaded.But I can't use LoadLanguage function before loading app , because there is no context in **main()** function.
How can I use **LoadLanguage** in **main()** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could suggest another approach. Calling `LoadLanguage()` in `didChangeDependencies ()` method or the `initState()`. Both of these execute before `build()` and therefore you could load whatever it is other parts of your app need in them so that when `build()` executes, your data is present.

Comment: It is not possible to run async functions in initState.It raise error in stateful screens.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Use didChangeDependencies().